# ForwardRef error in ListItem component when using NavLink

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

This is the ListItem component I'm using:

```
  <ListItem
    activeClassName={classes.activeListItem}
    className={classes.listItem}
    component={NavLink}
    to="/dashboard"
  >
    <ListItemIcon className={classes.listItemIcon}>
      <DashboardIcon />
    </ListItemIcon>
    <ListItemText
      classes={{ primary: classes.listItemText }}
      primary="Dashboard"
    />
  </ListItem>
```

This raises the error below:

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `ForwardRef(ListItem)`.
    in NavLink (created by ForwardRef(ListItem))
    in ForwardRef(ListItem) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(ListItem)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(ListItem)) (at sidebar/index.tsx:72)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(List))
    in ForwardRef(List) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(List)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(List)) (at sidebar/index.tsx:71)
    in nav (at sidebar/index.tsx:44)
    in Sidebar (created by WithStyles(Sidebar))
    in WithStyles(Sidebar) (at dashboard/index.tsx:45)
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Paper))
    in ForwardRef(Paper) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Paper)) (created by ForwardRef(Drawer))
    in div (created by ForwardRef(Drawer))
    in ForwardRef(Drawer) (created by WithStyles(ForwardRef(Drawer)))
    in WithStyles(ForwardRef(Drawer)) (at dashboard/index.tsx:37)
    in div (at dashboard/index.tsx:30)
    in Dashboard (created by WithStyles(Dashboard))
    in WithStyles(Dashboard) (created by Context.Consumer)
    in Route (at Routes.tsx:16)
    in Switch (at Routes.tsx:10)
    in Routes (at App.tsx:15)
    in Router (at App.tsx:14)
    in ThemeProvider (at App.tsx:13)
    in App (at src/index.tsx:7)
```

When I use the ListItem without a NavLink, everything works fine:

```
    <ListItem button key={text}>
      <ListItemIcon><InboxIcon /></ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={text} />
    </ListItem>
```

So I guess there's something wrong in the usage of `component` property of the ListItem but I can't find out why with my current level of knowledge :-)

Comment: See this part of the documentation: https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#third-party-routing-library

Comment: @RyanCogswell Thanks for the help. If you post your comment as an answer, I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ListItem` tries to [specify a ref](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/packages/material-ui/src/ListItem/ListItem.js#L1950) on the component you specify via the `component` prop.

Refs are not supported by function components except by wrapping them using React's [forwardRef](https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html).

React Router's [NavLink](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/modules/NavLink.js) is a function component and currently it is **not** wrapped by `React.forwardRef`.

The documentation [here](https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#third-party-routing-library) explains how to wrap react-router's `Link` (and `NavLink` just wraps `Link` so the same solution will work) so that it supports receiving a ref.

Answer (score 0):

The ButtonBase component provides a property to handle this use case: component.
This is achieved by attaching a ref to the component and expecting that the component forwards this ref to the underlying DOM node.

Follow this link:
https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/#third-party-routing-library